# "cannot load such file -- rubygems/defaults/operating_system" when installing Ruby 2.0.0

Tags: ruby, rvm

I have need of Ruby 2.0.0, so I turned to RVM to help manage my ruby installations.

However, when I do `rvm install ruby-2.0.0`, the installation ends up bombing out.

```
$ rvm install ruby-2.0.0
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.12/x86_64/ruby-2.0.0-p648.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates bundle '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' is already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/nick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.0.0-p648 - #downloading ruby-2.0.0-p648, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-2.0.0-p648 - #extracting ruby-2.0.0-p648 to /Users/nick/.rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p648....
ruby-2.0.0-p648 - #applying patch /Users/nick/.rvm/patches/ruby/2.0.0/openssl3.patch.
ruby-2.0.0-p648 - #applying patch /Users/nick/.rvm/patches/ruby/2.0.0/update-autoconf.patch.
ruby-2.0.0-p648 - #configuring.................................................
ruby-2.0.0-p648 - #post-configuration.
ruby-2.0.0-p648 - #compiling...................................................|
ruby-2.0.0-p648 - #installing..............
ruby-2.0.0-p648 - #making binaries executable..
ruby-2.0.0-p648 - #downloading rubygems-2.7.2
ruby-2.0.0-p648 - #extracting rubygems-2.7.2.....
ruby-2.0.0-p648 - #removing old rubygems........
ruby-2.0.0-p648 - #installing rubygems-2.7.2.
Error running 'env GEM_HOME=/Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648@global GEM_PATH= /Users/nick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin/ruby -d /Users/nick/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.7.2/setup.rb --no-document',
please read /Users/nick/.rvm/log/1510703598_ruby-2.0.0-p648/rubygems.install.log
```

So, I check out the log file as instructed, and this is what I see:

```
[2017-11-14 15:55:25] /Users/nick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin/ruby
current path: /Users/nick/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.7.2
PATH=/usr/local/opt/coreutils/bin:/usr/local/opt/pkg-config/bin:/usr/local/opt/libtool/bin:/usr/local/opt/automake/bin:/usr/local/opt/autoconf/bin:/Users/nick/.nvm/versions/node/v8.4.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/nick/.gvm/vertx/current/bin:/Users/nick/.gvm/springboot/current/bin:/Users/nick/.gvm/lazybones/current/bin:/Users/nick/.gvm/jbake/current/bin:/Users/nick/.gvm/groovyserv/current/bin:/Users/nick/.gvm/groovy/current/bin:/Users/nick/.gvm/griffon/current/bin:/Users/nick/.gvm/grails/current/bin:/Users/nick/.gvm/gradle/current/bin:/Users/nick/.gvm/glide/current/bin:/Users/nick/.gvm/gaiden/current/bin:/Users/nick/.gvm/crash/current/bin:/usr/local/mongodb_2.4.5/bin:/Users/nick/.gvm/grails/current/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/usr/local/mongodb_2.4.5/bin:/Users/nick/.gvm/grails/current/bin:/usr/local/scala-2.12.1/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/usr/local/git/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Users/nick/.rvm/bin
command(7): env GEM_HOME=/Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648@global GEM_PATH= /Users/nick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin/ruby -d /Users/nick/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.7.2/setup.rb --no-document
Exception `LoadError' at /Users/nick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:1087 - cannot load such file -- rubygems/defaults/operating_system
Exception `LoadError' at /Users/nick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:1096 - cannot load such file -- rubygems/defaults/ruby
YAML safe loading is not available. Please upgrade psych to a version that supports safe loading (>= 2.0).
Bundler 1.16.0 installed
RubyGems 2.7.2 installed
Regenerating binstubs
```

I'm not really sure what to make of this error. I've tried uninstalling 2.0.0 and installing it again, imploding & reinstalling rvm, even reinstalling ruby with homebrew and doing everything from scratch, but this error persists. Any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try installing Ruby using the `--rubygems ignore` option:

`$ rvm install ruby-2.0.0 --rubygems ignore`

Comment: What does this option do exactly?

Comment: for me, i got the mentioned error, but didnt need that particular version of Ruby, so I installed a different version, e.g. `rvm install 2.7` - note if you do `rvm list known` and choose one from the top of the list, it may work for you

Comment: and to make the version you installed the default, run the following: `rvm use 1.7 --default`

Comment: it is the ruby version issue. change from 2.x to 2.y and all will smooth. skipping rubygems directory doesn't seem right

Answer (score 9):

Mention a specific version of `rubygems` will work too

```
rvm reinstall ruby-head --rubygems 2.6.11
```

Comment: How do you know which version of rubygems you need though ? I know my project uses `ruby-2.3.0` but I have no idea what version of rubygems it was using

Comment: Hopefully this table is useful @GeoffreyH https://www.fastruby.io/blog/ruby/rails/versions/compatibility-table.html

Comment: Anecdotal evidence: trying to install Ruby 2.2.10 while mentioning rubygems 3.0.9 or later did not work. But this is what got me going: `CFLAGS="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration" rvm reinstall 2.2 --rubygems 1.7.2`