# error installing ruby 2.1.3 on mac os Catalina version 10.15.7 using RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rvm

I am unable to install ruby 2.1.3 on mac os Catalina version 10.15.7 using rvm

This is the error that I receive.

[image]

And these are the logs
[image]

I have tried
`brew update && brew install gmp && rvm reinstall 2.1.3`
and `rvm reinstall 2.1.3 --disable-binary` too. But both didn't work for me.

Comment: For the next one please paste the text instead of attaching a screenshot. You're an old user dude, you should know that. Thanks

Comment: Related with your question, [have you tried one of these solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47298306/895789)?

Comment: Yes, tried that one didn't work. Sorry for posting screenshots, really frustrated!

Comment: I had a lot of problems trying to install older ruby versions in catalina. I think it has something to do with the new command line tools. The only way I found around the problem was to isolate the application in a docker container using a linux distribution.
[This post might help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64231219/issues-with-installing-ruby-2-0-0-on-macos-catalina)